# How to manage both single and an array of json reponse from the same external system?

Tags: apex, json, callout, deserialize, httpresponse

I have a situation where when I make a callout I get a single json response like this:

```
{
    "Person": {
        "Infomration": {
            "IndividualInformation": {
                "IndividualCode": "XXXXXX",
                "IndividualType": {
                    "Resident": 0,
                    "Alive": "Yes",
                }
            },FamilyInformation": {
                "FamilyCode": 0101010,
                "PresentInFamily": 1
            }
        },
        ..... a really long json reponse
}
```

Notice that there is only a single `{}` indicating a single element. The problem is that sometimes the external system can send more than one `person` depending of the search result of the external system. I was not given a sample array response, but I am assuming it will be with like this:

```
[{
        "Person": {
            "Infomration": {
                "IndividualInformation": {
                    "IndividualCode": "XXXXXX",
                    "IndividualType": {
                        "Resident": 0,
                        "Alive": "Yes",
                    }
                },FamilyInformation": {
                    "FamilyCode": 0101010,
                    "PresentInFamily": 1
                }
            },
            ..... 
    }, "Person": {
"Infomration": {
            "IndividualInformation": {
                "IndividualCode": "XXXXXX",
                "IndividualType": {
                    "Resident": 0,
                    "Alive": "Yes",
                }
            },FamilyInformation": {
                "FamilyCode": 0101010,
                "PresentInFamily": 1
            }
        },
        ..... 
}]
```

I am trying to handle this as there are 2 different reponses. I tried using `JSON.deserializeUntyped`. But for single reponse I have to use this `(Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonBody);`. Obviously doesn't work for array of response. For array I have to use `(List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonBody);`. I can't simply cast it `(List<Object>)` for both array and single.

The only solution I found was:

```
String respBody = res.getBody();
if(!respBody.left(1).equalsIgnoreCase('[')) respBody = '[' + res.getBody() + ']';

dataFromSystemExternal = (List<ResponseSystemExternal>) JSON.deserialize(respBody, List<ResponseSystemExternal>.Class);
```

Basically, I am checking the very first char of the `respBody` to see if it is a '['. If not I am enclosing the `respBody` between '[' and ']' and deserializing the `respBody` into a List.

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use **JSON to Apex** to deal with dynamic responses.
https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/

Paste in the response with **multiple customers** and then create.  It will give you a test class and class to parse the response.

Once you have the parser in Salesforce, the class that is doing the callout can reference the code like this.

Apex Code:

//Parsing the response through the generated class

ParserClassName parsedResponse = ParserClassName .parse(responseBody);

//Looping through the people that are returned

for(ParserClassName.person currentPerson: parsedResponse.response.person){

}